# Why is the order of $GL(d,F) = (q^d-1)(q^d-q)...(q^d-q^{d-1})$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

$F$ is a field of order $q$.

We are essentially counting the total number of possible ordered bases in the vector space $F^d$.

The first vector has $q^d - 1$ possibilities because we need to exclude the zero vector.

The second vector cannot be a scalar multiple of the first vector, and there are $q$ scalars in $F$, so once we have chosen the first vector, there are $q^d-q$ possible ways to construct the second vector such that $v_1$ and $v_2$ are linearly independent.

But what about the third vector? Why are there $q^d-q^2$ possibilities?

Comment: Because it can be any vector except the $q^2$ linear combinations of the previous $2$ (they result in exactly $q^2$ vectors because the previous $2$ vector are linearly independent).

Comment: Thanks! I think I get it. $q^2$ is the number of ways to have two scalars in $F$